# Website does not display css correctly on Google Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am stuck with a problem on a website I created. The website worked fine a few weeks ago. Now the css doesn't render on chrome. It's www.gazosa.info. Also a few pics arent displaing on firefox but the structure seems fine. The only browser displaying everything is safari, which seems surprising for me.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your homepage size is more than 3MB. Site is loading in my machine but bit slow. due to heavy size and too many requests. https://www.dropbox.com/s/w71z8zl8mieytb6/Screenshot%202015-07-29%2017.16.04.png?dl=0

Please check this http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/lgB3G/http://www.gazosa.info/

Getting 404 errors so also make sure you have given proper permission to your files.

Thanks

Comment: True! agree with Shrinivas.

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked when I deleted some @font-face that I was not using anymore and added src to a <img tag. still don't know why these faults never seemed to be a problem before.

Answer (score 0):

You have used http://www.gazosa.info/docs.min.js on your website.

But this link is dead.

Fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked when I deleted some @font-face that I was not using anymore and added src to a <img tag. still don't know why these faults never seemed to be a problem before.